# SQL Server 2005 varchar loses decimal places converting to a decimal

Tags: sql-server, decimal

```
Declare @BadDecimal varchar(5)
Set @BadDecimal = '4.5'
Declare @GoodDecimal Decimal
Set @GoodDecimal = @BadDecimal
Select @GoodDecimal

--Outputs 5
```

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
Declare @GoodDecimal Decimal(2,1)
```

edit: changed to (2,1) after request.

Comment: You should probably edit your post.  Decimal(2,2) isn't right.  The minimum values for precision and scale to store 4.5 is Decimal(2,1).

Answer (score 4):

Coentjie beat me to it arrggg...

You need to declare your decimals using this format Decimal(p,s)

p = The maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision of 38. The default precision is 18.

s = The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

Comment: Good to be first ;-) normally i am the one that is just a little too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Set @BadDecimal = '4,5'`

Answer (score 1):

casting or converting to explicit decimal(digits, precision) works:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), '4.5')
SELECT CAST('4.5' AS DECIMAL(5,2))
```

SQLServer Help states that each combination of (digits, precision) is handled as separate data type.

Comment: This doesn't work if you use the parameter @BadDecimal in the string