# In SQL how can I convert a money datatype to a decimal?

Tags: sql, types, decimal, currency

I want to convert a money datatype to a decimal, because I want to record the results to 8 decimal places.

For example, in a currency rate table I see the rate stored as 2871047428.20 as a money datatype; using Microsoft SQL Management Studio, I want to divide that by 10000000 in order to achieve the result 287.10474282; however the result I am actually getting is 287.1047.

I believe the reason I am getting only the 4 decimal places is because it is money datatype, and therefore I think the way forward is to convert this to a decimal datatype....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here a comparison left column the decimal value, right column the calculated money value:

```
DECLARE @money AS money
SET @money = 2871047428.20
SELECT CAST(@money AS decimal(34,4)) / 10000000, @money / 10000000
```

See also here on Stack Overflow:

- [How do I convert from a money datatype in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532351/how-do-i-convert-from-a-money-datatype-in-sql-server)
- [SQL Server 2005 varchar loses decimal places converting to a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391117/sql-server-2005-varchar-loses-decimal-places-converting-to-a-decimal)

Comment: Thank you I am now progressing, but I can't use the SET command because I had used 2871047428.20 as an example. It is a currency exchange rate which varies according to the actual currency code (eg EUR, USD etc) and will need to pick up the latest currency rates from the table....

Comment: SELECT @exchangeReate = ... FROM ExchangeRate ... - BTW: Feel free to upvote and/or accept if it helped finding the solution. ;-)

Comment: Hi, I'm inching closer but still its not working correctly yet:-
DECLARE @exchangeRate AS money
SELECT @exchangeRate = CAST(Rate AS decimal(34,4)) / 10000000 
FROM...  Is this syntax right?  Yes I will vote later, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for all your help yesterday. In the end it was solved with the following coding:  SELECT     TOP (20) curcode AS 'Currency', curdate AS 'System Date', rate, cast((rate / cast(10000000 as float)) as decimal(20,8)) AS 'Rate' FROM/WHERE etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT CAST(currency_rate AS decimal) / 10000000 FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're all hitting oddities of decimal division
Here is my answer to [another thread, T-SQL Decimal Division Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423925/t-sql-decimal-division-accuracy/424052#424052)

And you may have implicit float conversions too because of [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) if you use 10000000.0

```
DECLARE @money AS money
SET @money = 2871047428.20
--Oddities
SELECT
    CAST(@money AS decimal(34,8)) / 10000000,
    CAST(@money AS decimal(34,8)) / 10000000.0,
    CAST(@money AS decimal(34,8)) / 10000000.00,
    CAST(@money AS decimal(34,8)) / 10000000.000,
    CAST(@money AS decimal(34,8)) / 10000000.0000
--Should be safe. My brain hurts if I work through p and s
SELECT
    CAST(@money AS decimal(38,8)) / CAST(10000000 AS decimal(8,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

splattne's answer is almost correct, except for two minor changes:

```
DECLARE @money AS money
SET @money = 2871047428.20
SELECT CAST(@money AS decimal(34,6)) / 10000000.0, @money / 10000000.0
```

This will give the correct answer: 287.10474282. What I did is changing the precision value and adding the ".0" to the division value.

The only thing that puzzles me right now is the fact I have to cast the value as decimal(34,6) instead of the expected decimal(34,8).

So, I wrote the query in another way, which makes more sense to me:

```
DECLARE @money AS money
SET @money = 2871047428.20
SELECT CAST((@money / 10000000.0) AS decimal(34,8)), @money / 10000000.0
```

Please see which one works for you.